# How to enable an dotnet 6 client app in a linux container to authenticate with user/password against a kestrel server with kerberos

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, authentication, kerberos, dotnet-httpclient

I'm developing a Service in ASP.Net-Core (.net6) that connects to a BusinessCentral OData API.
The Server has SSL/Kerberos enabled and I have a user and password to authenticate with.
I use the AddHttpClient-IServiceCollectionExtension in my Program.cs like:

```
services.AddHttpClient([name], httpClient =>
{
  httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(config[BaseUrl]);
}).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
  new HttpClientHandler()
  {
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
      config[Username],
      config[Password],
      config[Domain])
  }
);
```

...and inject the IHttpClientFactory to my client-class:

```
MyODataClient(IHttpClientFactory factory)
{
  _client = factory!.CreateClient([name]);
}

public HttpResponseMessage GetEntity(Entity src)
{
  var path = $"{src.Type}('{src.SysId}')?";
  var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, path);
  var response = _client.SendAsync(request);
  return response;
}
```

So far so good. Everything ist fine and works (with swagger)!
BUT...
When I start this service within a linux Docker container, I get the error:

**GSSAPI operation failed with error - Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Cannot find KDC for realm "[domain]").**

---

Then I tried:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
  options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

Now Swagger ask me for username and password. It doesn't work but I think this is why I don't passthrough the headers from swagger to BC19... with HeaderPropagation or so (??).
Btw. I need to use a static user. No interaction...

---

I also read and tried keytab-stuff... But everything I read was >2 years old. Does anybody know, how to deal with it in .net6? It seems to be quite easy but I don't find the two lines of code, that I need to connect the httpClientHandler (credentials) with the AuthenticationBuilder (negotiate)

Maybe this log helps:

```
Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
[17:20:26 INF] AuthenticationScheme: Negotiate was challenged.
[17:20:26 INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:49179/Entity?[...]. - - - 401 0 - 28.0138ms
```

best regards

Oli

Comment: If you are not logged in then your log content is normal. It is by design, it comes from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.

Comment: If this log appears after you are authenticated, it may be caused by invoking an authenticated Service. The attribute `[AllowAnonymous]` can be added to this interface to disable authentication.

Comment: Your error message is caused by kerberos. Because the KDC was not found in the requested realm. Make sure that the Kerberos configuration file (krb5.conf) specifies a KDC in the realm section.

Comment: Thank you. I feared that too, and hoped I could avoid that krb5-stuff because is going to be a reusable microservice that has to be configurable for different external services. And now I have to put configs to the /etc?!?!? And only becasue I have to use linux containers...

Comment: I have a question, if krb5-stuff can be avoided, can it still be used normally?